# Sybase openqueries?

Tags: sql, sybase, openquery

Does open query exist in sybase ? Or more generally, in sybase, what are the possible way to select among the result of a procedure (temporary tables, out params, others ??)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify output parameters for a stored procedure by adding the keyword "output" after the parameter in the "Create Procedure MyStoredProcedure..." command.

Temp Tables of course exist, local or Global.

T-SQL under Sybase IQ you can also select from a stored procedure so something like this, assume your procedure is called "MyStoredProcedure"

```
SELECT MyId
FROM MyStoredProcedure()
```

Finally you can also create derived tables (at least it works in Sybase IQ) like this to join with your stored procedure results

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.Address, t2.MyId
FROM MyTable t1, (SELECT MyId FROM MyStoredProcedure()) t2
WHERE t1.MyId = t2.MyId
```

Comment: Derived tables seems to be what I am looking for but does it work in sybase ase 12 ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not worked with ASE for a while but I think the following link explains the process fairly well.

http://www.sypron.nl/proctab.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: derived tables came with Sybase ASE 12.5.1